# Read every string inside a JSON

Tags: c++, json, file, iostream

So I am trying to read every string inside a JSON file using https://github.com/nlohmann/json and push the strings inside a map. I need this to read every string in a language file for serialization. EXAMPLE:

```
{
     "StringToRead1" : "Test",
     "StringToRead2" : "Another Test"
}
```

So i tried to use an iterator and push everything in:

```
std::ifstream iStream(filePath);
if(!iStream.is_open()) { std::cout << "Cannot open the strings language file.\n"; return -1; }
nlohmann::json json = nlohmann::json::parse(iStream);

for(auto a = json.begin(); a != json.end(); ++a) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator iterator = m_Strings.begin();
    m_Strings.insert(iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(a.key, a.value));
}
```

I am getting these compile errors:
error C3867: 'nlohmann::detail::iter_impl>>>::key': syntax not standard; use'&' to create a pointer
error C3867: 'nlohmann::detail::iter_impl>>>::value': syntax not standard; use'&' to create a pointer

Thanks for the help, i hope i was clear enough.

SOLUTION:
a.key() and a.value() instead of a.key and a.value
THANK YOU

Comment: what are you getitng?

Comment: updated the post, even if i add the & in a.key/a.value still gives me a syntax error

Comment: There's an example of this on the README on the page you linked to... (ctrl+f "special iterator member functions for objects")

Comment: Also that's a very verbose way of writing to a `std::map`... why not just `m_Strings[a.key()] = a.value();`?

Comment: or `m_Strings.emplace(a.key(), a.value());`

Comment: i can't because i don't know the actual number of strings i have to save

Answer (score 1):

the key and value are function call so you need to use function operator:

```
for(auto a = json.begin(); a != json.end(); ++a) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator iterator = m_Strings.begin();
    m_Strings.insert(iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(a.key(), a.value()));
}
```

insted of

```
for(auto a = json.begin(); a != json.end(); ++a) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator iterator = m_Strings.begin();
    m_Strings.insert(iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(a.key, a.value));
}
```